# Error with Calendar overlays

Tags: calendar, app-part, overlay

I have created a calendar view which is a calendar overlay of Client Review Dates and Policy Valuation Dates.

It works perfectly, however when I then add that calendar into my home page as an app part there is no information on it.

How do I resolve this issue? I made the calendar overlays by following these steps:

- https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/including-list-and-library-items-in-a-sharepoint-2010-calendar-overlay/
- https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/color-code-events-on-a-sharepoint-calendar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calendar overlays only work from the Calendars themselves not list views (which is what you are adding to your home page).  If you want to keep that - then use a link that points to the calendar view where you have configured the overlays.

Comment: Thanks man! That worked. It's a bit of a pain to have to go to another web page but if that's the only option that that's fine, thank you so much.